# Distributed training on PyTorch and Spot checkpoints in SageMaker

Tags: pytorch, amazon-sagemaker, distributed-training, amz-sagemaker-distributed-training

I'm building custom model on PyTorch and want to know how to implement **snapshot logic** for **distributed training**.

If a model is trained on multiple spot instances and the model is implemented on BYO PyTorch image, how dpes Sagemaker know which snapshot to load for a failed job? E.g. there are 4 spot instances and they produce 4 snapshots. Let's say one instance is terminated - how SageMaker knows which snapshot to load?

Answer (score 0):

**Saving** - If you're doing data parallelization, then [checkpoint](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/713fff33d6bffaabb1d9ace369c30a9aecc897a2/sagemaker-python-sdk/tensorflow_script_mode_horovod/mnist_hvd.py#L121) only from the first GPU (rank=0), as all GPUs see the same state after a mini-batch.
**Loading** - SageMaker will load the last checkpoint directory to all instances, so load it for each of the GPUs (ranks), and continue from there.